# How to ask user to input a filepath for a file while using pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I am new to coding and am trying out some pandas stuff and would like to know how to ask the user for the file-path of a file which I will be using pandas with later, and to subsequently open that file, which will be a csv file. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the code:

```
import csv

import pandas as pd
filepath = ("Enter filepath name: ")
df = pd.read_csv (rfilepath)
print (df)
```

Comment: `filepath = input("Enter filepath name: ")`?

Answer (score 1):

You got it pretty much spot on already!

```
import pandas as pd
    
filepath = input('Enter filepath name: ')
df = pd.read_csv(filepath)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Say you had a file `fruits.csv` with the following contents:

```
apples,bananas,cherries
5,3,10
```

The following code that utilizes [`os.path.isfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile) would allow you to ensure the user has entered a valid file path before attempting [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
import os
import pandas as pd

csv_filepath = input("Please enter a valid file path to a csv: ")
while not os.path.isfile(csv_filepath):
    print("Error: That is not a valid file, try again...")
    csv_filepath = input("Please enter a valid file path to a csv: ")

try:
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_filepath)
    print(df)
    # Add your other code to manipulate the dataframe read from the csv here
except BaseException as exception:
    print(f"An exception occurred: {exception}")
```

**Example Usage:**

```
Please enter a valid file path to a csv: vegetables.csv
Error: That is not a valid file, try again...
Please enter a valid file path to a csv: fruits.csv
   apples  bananas  cherries
0       5        3        10
```